# How to switch to SLAB from SLUB?

Tags: linux, fedora

I am running Fedora 20, on which SLUB is by default the active memory allocator. (see /boot/config-$(your kernel version)

Now I want to test SLUB against SLAB. Is there anyway to change the active allocator to SLAB? How am I supposed to modify the above config file? Or I must recompile the kernel (I hope not)?

Thanks.

Comment: AFIAK, the slab allocator is a compile-time option for the kernel, and is not modularly replacable. Which sorta makes sense given how low-level it is - how would the kernel operate during the time when you've unloaded one allocator and are working on allocating the new one?

Comment: I found the "solution": recompiling the kernel with default memory allocator set to SLAB. Then boot from the newly built kernel:)